# Filling missing fields - the new unknown value

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science

I'm trying to fill missing values in my dataset.

```
data.count()

PassengerId    891
Survived       891
Pclass         891
Sex            891
Age            891
SibSp          891
Parch          891
Ticket         891
Fare           891
Cabin          204
Embarked       891
Title          889
dtype: int64
```

As we can see - there is a lot of missing values in "Cabin". So I tried to fill this values. First, I changed every A12, A15 etc. to only "A".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('titanic_data/train.csv')
newdata = [data]
for dataset in newdata:
    dataset['Cabin'] = dataset['Cabin'].str[:1]
```

Created a bar chart before filling missing values.

```
Pclass1 = data[data['Pclass']==1]['Cabin'].value_counts()
Pclass2 = data[data['Pclass']==2]['Cabin'].value_counts()
Pclass3 = data[data['Pclass']==3]['Cabin'].value_counts()

df = pd.DataFrame([Pclass1, Pclass2, Pclass3])
df.index = ['1st class', '2nd class', '3rd class']
df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,5))


plt.legend()
```

[image]

And then I changed letters to numbers.

```
cabin_mapping = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 0.25,
    "C": 0.5,
    "D": 0.75,
    "E": 1,
    "F": 1.25,
    "G": 1.5,
    "T": 1.75
}
for dataset in newdata:
    dataset['Cabin'] = dataset['Cabin'].map(cabin_mapping)
```

Filled missing values:

```
data['Cabin'].fillna(data.groupby('Pclass')['Cabin'].transform('median'), inplace=True)
```

And now I have one unknown value - 1.125. What does it means?

[image]